# nodejs POST json object which contains array of objects

Tags: node.js

From client side I am sending object as

```
{
    name: xyz,
        data : [
            { k1: v1, k2: v2 },
            { k1: v3, k2: v4 }
        ]
}
```

But on server side I am getting it as

```
{
    name: xyz,
        data : {
            k1: [v1, v3], k2: [v2, v4]
    }
}
```

I am uploading image along with it. `Content-type` is `multipart/form-data`
On serverside using `body-parser`

Comment: that's cool. unfortunately the question is missing the code that causes this problem to occur and proof that a problem exists (network log output)

Comment: My guess is you're mis-interpreting the results. Most likely the client is in fact sending it in the format your server is receiving it in ( as a query string or form params rather than json )

Comment: Try adding in the code that is involved with this problem

Comment: Upload.upload({
                url: <url>,
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
                arrayKey: '',
                data: {data: $scope.formData}
            }).then(successfn, errorfn)

formData as one file to be uploaded and above json object.
On server side I am just printing json object received

Answer (score 0):

This looks issue due to ng-upload

{
    url: 'url',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
    arrayKey: '',
    data: {file : $files, data: $data}
}

arrayKey field needed to upload multiple files. Removing it leads to error "Unexpected field" due to issue in ng-upload
But adding above fields causes the issue mention above. Array elements in JSON objects are getting merged.
If field arrayKey is removed, then correct JSON object is received at server side